# Gitlab on Apache2 with SSL

Tags: apache, ubuntu, redirect, apache2, gitlab

I have successfully installed Gitlab on Ubuntu 14.04 using https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404 but I am struggling to make redirect and access it through web (https://my.example.com/gitlab).

I have modified `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`to:

> external_url 'https://my.example.com/gitlab'
>
> nginx['enable'] = false

And reconfigured with `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

If I uncomment:

> web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']

I get:

> Recipe Compile Error in
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab-ee/recipes/default
>
> NoMethodError
>   ------------- undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
>
> Cookbook Trace:
>   ---------------   /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/config.rb:21:in
>   `from_file'
>
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:26:in`
>   from_file'
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab-ee/recipes/default.rb:18:in
>   `from_file'
>
> Relevant File Content:
>   ---------------------- /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/config.rb:
>
> 14:  # See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and  15:  # limitations under the License.  16:  #  17: 
>   18:  Gitlab[:node] = node  19:  20:  if
>   File.exists?('/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb')  21>>
>   Gitlab.from_file('/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb')  22:  end  23:  24: 
>   node.consume_attributes(Gitlab.generate_config(node['fqdn']))  25:

I have tried adding various gitlab.conf to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` but https://my.example.com/gitlab does not redirect to Gitlab login page, I get 'Page not found' from Redmine service which runs on home page. Current `default-ssl.conf` uses `DocumentRoot /var/www` while Gitlab `DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public`. Apache2 is configured to use SSL.

**UPDATE 1**

I have made symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public /var/www/gitlab
```

So now it can be configured in default-ssl.conf.

```
Alias /gitlab "/var/www/gitlab"
```

Does not forward to Gitlab homepage, while

```
Alias /gitlab "/var/www/gitlab/deploy.html"
```

works well. What is Gitlab home page directory? Where is index.html file?

**UPDATE 2**

If I add

```
RackBaseURI /gitlab
RailsBaseURI /gitlab
<Directory /var/www/gitlab>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

I get error after entering https://my.example.com/gitlab/

> Web application could not be started
>
> It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:
>
> bundle install
>
> If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application > being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check > the following:
>
> ```
> Is this app supposed to be run as the www-data user?
> Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
> ```
>
> -------- The exception is as follows: -------
>   Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
>
> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize'
>     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in`map!'
>     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
>     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in`specs'
>     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
>     /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in`requested_specs'

The exception above was solved after updating Ruby.

**UPDATE 3**

Now I get

[image]

with

```
Alias /gitlab "/var/www/gitlab"
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Directory /var/www/gitlab>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        PassengerAppRoot "/var/www/gitlab"
        RailsBaseURI /var/www/gitlab
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

How to configure Gitlab and Apache2 to get Gitlab first page when entering https://my.example.com/gitlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had other service working on 8080 so I have changed Unicorn port to 9099.
Modified Gitlab configuration `sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
external_url 'https://subdomain.example.com/gitlab'

web_server['username'] = 'apache' #'gitlab-www'
web_server['group'] = 'apache' #'gitlab-www'

nginx['enable'] = false

unicorn['listen'] = '127.0.0.1'
unicorn['port'] = 9099
```

Reconfigured Gitlab: `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Modified Apache configuration `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` with adding:

```
ProxyPass         /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:9099/gitlab
ProxyPassReverse  /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:9099/gitlab
RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

Reloaded it:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/822716/gitlab-https-uri-for-repository-cloning-does-not-work-ssl-host-could-not-be-ve

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your Apache configuration is not proxying to the GitLab server on port 8080 (unicorn). There are example Apache configuration files available at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache.

There's also a good post explaining the steps to use Apache with GitLab Omnibus at http://ryansechrest.com/2015/08/use-apache-instead-of-built-in-nginx-in-gitlab-ce/. It's a little over a year old, so the Apache configuration may be a little outdated. Use the guide, but substitute the Apache configuration from the `gitlab-recipes` link above and it should work.

Comment: Now I am getting Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound).

Comment: What command are you running when you get this error? What else did you change other than Apache configuration? Changing Apache configuration would not cause the GitLab application to suddenly throw these errors.

Comment: I have solved this problem. I had it after entering Gitlab URL in browser, it was because of incorrect Ruby version and lack of permissions. Now it forwards to /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public folder and I see "Index of /gitlab" with containing files instead of Gitlab home page.

Comment: I'm glad you got past that rake error. Now you're experiencing the problem I described in my answer - you're pointing at the GitLab public webserver folder, but not proxying to the actual application. See the links in my answer for next steps.